# Cannot open PDF file in Jupyter Notebook (Chrome)

Tags: python, pdf, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

I usually run my Jupyter Notebook on Chrome and can directly open PDF files by clicking on the file name.

However after updating my Google Chrome browser, I noticed that I cannot open my PDF files using Jupyter Notebook anymore, and I get error message:

```
localhost is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

[image: Chrome error: ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT]

I **have removed all extensions, browsing data, cookies etc.** in my Chrome browser but the error still exists.

I have reinstalled my Chrome and my Anaconda several times.
I tried to debug this issue by using the inspect function by right clicking on the error page, and get **304 Not Modified** [image: 304 Not Modified]

I am not sure if it is something wrong with my chrome://flags/, and I have reset all to default.
I also tried Notebook in Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox, all works fine with PDFs.
However, when I rollback my Chrome version, Chrome+Jupyter is able to open PDF files.
Finally, I can simply opening a PDF file using Chrome without using Jupyter Notebook. Still, I wish to figure out why I can't open it in Jupyter anymore.
My Chrome version is: Version 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved by using the latest version of chrome 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)
[image]